# How to avoid backtracking parsing SQL with FParsec?

Tags: fparsec, sql-parser

I'm parsing SQL (Sqlite) using FParsec, and I'm running into issues with backtracking when parsing constructs like `START_KEYWORD element_0, …, element_N END_KEYWORD`. Since the parser for recognizing identifiers also recognizes keywords, I have to make sure that I try to parse the keyword first and only if that fails then I continue with the identifier. For that, I'm using the parser combinator `many1Till`, but it still seems like I cannot escape backtracking.

Here's an example of how I'm currently parsing an `ORDER BY` clause:

```ml
let sep1CommaEnd p endP =
    let commaOrEnd = symbol S.Comma <|> followedBy endP
    many1Till (p .>> commaOrEnd) (followedBy endP)

let orderBy =
    parse {
        do! keyword K.Order >>. keyword K.By
        let! xs = sep1CommaEnd ident (keyword K.Asc <|> keyword K.Desc)
        let! asc = (keyword K.Asc >>. preturn true <|> (keyword K.Desc >>. preturn false) <|> preturn true )
        return { columns = xs; asc = asc }
    }
```

This implementation has a few issues:

- It uses `followedBy` twice in `sep1CommaEnd`, which can cause backtracking.
- It repeats parsing the keyword used for ending the construct, which is inefficient.

To solve these issues, I came up with the idea of creating a parser combinator called `sepBy1Cont` that allows me to:

- End right after the keyword used for ending is detected.
- Accumulate all results, including the one returned by the parser of the keyword used for ending.
  Here's my implementation of `sepBy1Cont`:

```ml
type Either<'a, 'b> =
    | Left of 'a
    | Right of 'b

let sepBy1Cont (p: Parser<'a, unit>) (sepEnd: Parser<Either<'b, 'c>, unit>) =
    let rec loop (acc: 'a list) =
        parse {
            let! x = p
            let! d = sepEnd

            match d with
            | Left _ -> return! loop (x :: acc)
            | Right next ->
                let xs = List.rev (x :: acc)
                return (xs, next)
        }

    loop []
```

My questions are:

- Is there a better way to solve this problem in FParsec that I'm missing?
- If `sepBy1Cont` is a good solution, is there a better way to implement it? Should I learn about the internals of FParsec to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

Answering your 1st question (in general): There are many builtin string parsers in FParsec that can / should be used for clarity and performance.

Given a pseudo-grammar that should be parsed:

`START_KEYWORD element_0, …, element_N END_KEYWORD`

Here's an idea:

```ml
let sigStart = "START"
let sigEnd = "END"

let pDemo : Parser<_,unit> = 
    let field = many1Chars2 letter (letter <|> digit <|> pchar '_')
    let separator = pchar ',' .>> spaces
    let fields = sepBy1 field separator
    between (pstring sigStart .>> spaces1) (spaces1 >>. pstring sigEnd) fields

let run p s =
    match runParserOnString p () "" s with
    | Success (result, _, _) -> printfn "Success: %A" result
    | Failure (msg, _, _) -> printfn "Failure: %s" msg

$"{sigStart} field_0, field_1, field_N {sigEnd}"
|> run pDemo

// Success: ["field_0"; "field_1"; "field_N"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I think using `between` is a good idea in that specific case. However, for a more general one like 

`SELECT col0, col1, … (FROM | ORDER BY)` 

doing 

`between (keyword "SELECT") (keyword "FROM" <|> (keyword "ORDER" >>. keyword "BY")) columnParser` 

would mean that the result doesn't tell me exactly if it ended with `FROM` or `ORDER BY`. 

Thus, for continuing parsing after the result of `between`, I would have to parse `FROM | ORDER BY` again. This means I'll end up with the same problem I'm trying to solve.